# strange behaviour of php

Tags: php, c++

Today I noticed an ambiguity in php. I ran this code

```
$i = 5;
$i = $i ++;
var_dump($i); //output 5 instead of 6
```

Let us assume the initial value of `$i is 5`. Now the new value should be 6 but it in fact turns out to be `5`. When I did the same thing in `C++` I got `6` as expected.
Is it some bug in php which went unnoticed for so many years or is it some thing else. Can some one please explain it?

Comment: Good question, but that looks like very error-prone code and is bound to confuse people.  To increment `$i`, use standard conventions.  Pick either `$i++` or `$i += 1` or `$i = $i + 1` (or some other obvious method) instead of mixing them.  Assigning to the result of a post increment operation just looks weird.

Comment: Don't know about PHP, but in C++, `i = i++;` is undefined. The `6` you got as a result is meaningless.

Comment: should it be like $i=$i++ is same as $i=$i and then $i++ ie $i=5 and $i++ gives $i=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out the manual for incrementation/decrementation operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php). The behavior you ask is normal, just goes against your intuition as a C++ developer.

$i++ *first* returns the value of $i then executes and increment while ++$i increments $i before returning it.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you assume the value *should be* 6?

`$i` is being incremented, the value *before* the incrementing is returned (because you're using the *post increment operator*) and assigned to `$i`. Seems logical.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$i = ++$i;
```

and you'll get the right result.

The problem is that if you do `$i = $i++` then `$i` is incremented after the statement but you are assigning it to the old on the other side, so it never gets to increment the variable